# Get variable from input and use it to change css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input field with `id="search"`.

```
<input id="search" type="text" />
```

Also there are few `<div>`'s that contains some text, like this:

```
<div id="textblock">Some text here</div>
<div id="textblock">Some other text here</div>
<div id="textblock">Few strokes</div>
<div id="textblock">More words</div>
```

I need to change style of a `<div>` (`display:none`) if that `<div>` had a text that user types in input field on the go.

For example, if value in the input would be "strokes", div (or divs) with word "strokes" disappears:

```
<div id="textblock">Some text here</div>
<div id="textblock">Some other text here</div>
<div id="textblock">More words</div>
```

I was looking for a jQuery solution, and I found some parts of code, but I can't put them together into one working piece. I know I should use `keyUp()` function, `:contains()` etc.

Comment: what have tried so far?

Comment: The same `id` shouldn't be used for more than one element per page, use classes instead (change `id="textblock"` to `class="textblock"`).

Comment: Just curious: why would you want this? What are you using this for?

Comment: I need it to make some kind of a spotlight search.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `id` attributes must be **unique** - you may not have multiple elements with the same ID. Instead you should use a `class` attribute:

```
<div class="textblock">Some text here</div>
<div class="textblock">Some other text here</div>
<div class="textblock">Few strokes</div>
<div class="textblock">More words</div>
```

To then filter you can use [jQuery's `:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to determine which of your `.textblock` elements contain the text entered into your `input` element. For this I'm using a [`blur` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) which will trigger when the `input` element no longer has focus:

```
$('#search').on('blur', function() {
    $('.textblock:contains(' + this.value + ')').hide();
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/yxp0zmz3/).

If you want this to happen as soon as content is entered into the `input` element, we can use an `input` event handler instead and combine `:contains()` with [jQuery's `:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to show elements which may have previously been hidden:

```
$('#search').on('input', function() {
    $('.textblock:contains(' + this.value + ')').hide();
    $('.textblock:not(:contains(' + this.value + '))').show();
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/yxp0zmz3/1/).

As pointed out by Dreamonic in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198709/get-variable-from-input-and-use-it-to-change-css-classes/25198794?noredirect=1#comment39242309_25198794) here, if you then want to handle the user removing the content from the `input` element, we need to ensure that we don't match the empty input against the `.textblock` contents. We can do this by using `trim()`:

```
$('#search').on('input', function() {
    if (this.value.trim().length > 0) {
        $('.textblock:contains(' + this.value + ')').hide();
        $('.textblock:not(:contains(' + this.value + '))').show();
    }
    else
        $('.textblock').show();
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/yxp0zmz3/3/).

[image: Example]

Comment: Your code fails when the user enters something, and then empties the input field. No lines are shown after doing that. I've updated the JSFiddle to ignore an empty input field, or spaces. [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dreamonic/yxp0zmz3/2/)

Comment: @Dreamonic both demos are working correctly for me on Chrome. The `blur` event handler doesn't have the `:not(:contains(...))` which is needed to re-display the content which does not match the input - but the `input` event does have this.

Comment: Well, they certainly behave different from my demo, in which I solved your "bugs". But I don't know which of the demos is the OP's desired result, so that's for him to decide.

Comment: @Dreamonic oh I see what you mean. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: Glad to help, certainly because your answer is the best explained one IMO.

Comment: I notice the same thing, both on Firefox and Chrome. When you empty field, all the div with class="textblock" disapear.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel this issue has been fixed following Dreamonic's comments. See the end of my answer.

Comment: Try to input the word "More". Result is unexpectable. Or even simply the letter "m".

Answer (score 0):

Id's in your DOM should be unique. So changed your id's to classes for demo. Use [**.blur()**](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and [**:contains()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/). Try this:

```
$("#search").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length)
        $("div.textblock:contains("+$(this).val()+")").hide();
    else
         $("div.textblock").show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9h4pxvb6/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
 $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
    if($( this ).text().contains($("#search").text()))
      $(this).hide();
 });
```

try above code on blur event of textbox